# DXL Script to Export DOORS Object Information to Microsoft Word - Randomly Dropping Information

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a DXL script that is supposed to go through each object in the selected module and export various object information based on the object data to a Microsoft Word file.  It generally works, but I am having a problem where at random points in the module the data doesn't get pasted into the Word document.

There are a few functions to perform the export of data, and they are called depending on the DOORS object:

- put_heading_in_word( string s ) - puts heading number and heading text in a larger font
- put_plain_text_in_word( string s ) - puts plain text in Word document
- put_new_line_in_word() - puts a carriage return in Word
- put_object_text_in_word( Object ob ) - copies the text from the passed in DOORS object to Word

Here are the functions:

```
/****************************************************************************************
* put_new_line_in_word
*****************************************************************************************/
void put_new_line_in_word()
{
    clear oleAutoArgs
    put(oleAutoArgs, 1) // 0=wdCollapseEnd, 1=wdCollapseStart
    oleMethod(objSel, "Collapse", oleAutoArgs)
    setRichClip(richText "\n" )
    oleMethod(objSel, "Paste")
}//put_new_line_in_word


/****************************************************************************************
* put_plain_text_in_word
*****************************************************************************************/
void put_plain_text_in_word(string s)
{
    clear oleAutoArgs
    put(oleAutoArgs, 1) // 0=wdCollapseEnd, 1=wdCollapseStart
    oleMethod(objSel, "Collapse", oleAutoArgs)
    copyToClipboard( s )
    oleGet(objSel, "Font", oleFont)
    olePut(oleFont, "Size", 11)
    oleMethod(objSel, "Paste")

}//put_plain_text_in_word

/****************************************************************************************
* put_heading_in_word
*****************************************************************************************/
void put_heading_in_word( string s )
{
    clear oleAutoArgs
    put(oleAutoArgs, 1) // 0=wdCollapseEnd, 1=wdCollapseStart
    oleMethod(objSel, "Collapse", oleAutoArgs)
    copyToClipboard( s )
    oleGet(objSel, "Font", oleFont)
    olePut(oleFont, "Size", 18)
    oleMethod(objSel, "Paste")
}//put_heading_in_word


/****************************************************************************************
* put_object_text_in_word
*****************************************************************************************/
void put_object_text_in_word(Object ob)
{
    clear oleAutoArgs
    put(oleAutoArgs, 1) // 0=wdCollapseEnd, 1=wdCollapseStart
    oleMethod(objSel, "Collapse", oleAutoArgs)
//  setRichClip(richText richText(ob."Object Text"))
    setRichClip(richText(ob."Object Text"))
    oleMethod(objSel, "Paste")

}//put_object_text_in_word
```

Here is an example of how they are used:

```
/****************************************************************************************
* Export_object
*   This is called for each object
*****************************************************************************************/
void Export_object (Module m, Object obj)
{

// allows the the use of attribute exists
current = m


    if ( isValidObject(obj))
    {
        temp_str = obj."Object Heading"
        if(!null temp_str)
        {
            put_plian_text_in_word("ID: ")
            put_plian_text_in_word(identifier(obj))
            put_new_line_in_word
            
            temp_str = number(obj)
            put_heading_in_word(temp_str)
            put_heading_in_word("  ")
            temp_str = obj."Object Heading"
            put_heading_in_word(temp_str)
            put_new_line_in_word
        
        
        }
        else
        {
        
        
            put_plian_text_in_word("ID: ")
            put_plian_text_in_word(identifier(obj))
            put_new_line_in_word
            
            temp_str = obj."Requirement"
            put_plian_text_in_word("Requirement: " temp_str)
            put_new_line_in_word
            
            temp_str = obj."Derived"
            put_plian_text_in_word("Derived: " temp_str)
            put_new_line_in_word
            
            temp_str = obj."DO-178 Level"
            put_plian_text_in_word("DO-178 Level: " temp_str)
            put_new_line_in_word
            
            temp_str = obj."Safety"
            put_plian_text_in_word("Safety: " temp_str)
            put_new_line_in_word        
            
            put_plian_text_in_word("Object Text: ")
            put_new_line_in_word
            put_object_text_in_word(obj)
            if(oleCopy(obj))
            {
                oleMethod(objSel, "Paste")
                put_new_line_in_word
            }
            
            temp_str = obj."Justify"
            put_plian_text_in_word("Justify: " temp_str)
            put_new_line_in_word    
        }

    }
}
```

My initial thought was that there were too many accesses to the OLE interface and things were getting dropped, so I created functions that used Buffer variables where I put the individual strings into the buffer and stopped using the "put_new_line_in_word" function and just placed '\n' in the buffer.  Now I just lose bigger chunks of data, and it didn't seem to reduce the frequency of losing data.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the Buffer based versions of the put_heading_in_word() and put_plain_text_in_word(), I placed "print()" statements to see if the functions were actually executing, and I verified that the buffers had the correct content after the function had been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is an unresolved issue with DOORS and Windows 10. The usual way to export to a Word document is using the Windows clipboard. The memory management seems to have changed in Windows 10, which throws OLE-Errors / OLE problems. That's also, why the issue is not reproducible all of the time.

I have no actual solution for you. As a workaround, if you have the possibility to use Windows 7, I would suggest to use it, until IBM or Microsoft are fixing this issue, (in the IBM DOORS Release Notes, I have not seen a fix regarding this issue, until the current release 9.7.2.1).

Comment: Thanks Fred.  I do have a Windows 7 server that has DOORS on it, but it doesn't have Microsoft Office.  I'm trying to get it installed, but I can't find the right workflow in the vast morass of the IT help desk ...

Comment: I was able to get access to a VM running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, and the script worked as expected.  I was able to generate the Word files without any data being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the Clipboard history in settings for clipboard- settings-system-then turn off Cliboard history feature if on. seems to have fixed my issue - however i did also reduce the number of files I was exporting at one time as well. from 20 to 10 at a time.